# Should array's length be set to zero after use?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm wondering if setting Delphi's array's length to 0 after use is a correct practice or not.

```
var
  MyArray : array of TObject;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, N);
  // do something with MyArray (add items and use it..)
  SetLength(MyArray, 0);
end;
```

Is there a reason why I should set length to 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `MyArray` is a local variable then there is no reason at all to finalise the variable in the code presented. As soon as the variable leaves scope, it will be finalised. There's nothing to be gained by doing so explicitly.

Sometimes however, you have a variable whose scope extends significantly longer than your use of the array. In those scenarios it can be useful to finalise the variable as soon as you have finished with it so that the memory is returned.

Personally I would prefer

```
MyArray := nil;
```

or

```
Finalize(MyArray);
```

which in my opinion more readily jump out as finalisation statements. Your

```
SetLength(MyArray, 0);
```

can look like you are allocating when skimming the code.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic arrays are automatically freed when nothing is referencing it.

I would prefer the following method if you need to do this manually. This looks clear to me than other methods.

```
MyDynamicArray = nil;
```

It sets the natural environment of zero reference and let the memory manager to free it in due course.

Comment: I think it's a bit strong to declare that way to be the "best". Could you at least justify why it is "better" than the two alternatives?

Comment: I didn't really compare my answer with yours. Dynamic arrays are managed and would be freed if nothing referenced it. Now when you set nil to the pointer, you take the reference off manually (assuming that there is no other reference). So I thought it would be best to set the natural environment for the managing process to take action on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is more explicit what you intend to do, it conveys the semantics, not the implementation. Outside of that consideration SetLength-0 is the same of course.

Comment: @CharlieH I wasn't comparing answers. You made a comparative statement concerning the three ways to finalize a dynamic array. Namely `SetLength(arr, 0)`, `Finalize(arr)` and `arr := nil`. Those three statements have identical effect. So my point was that you should clarify why you felt one to be "better" that the others.

Comment: I'm not sure about the update. Do you appreciate that the three options presented in my previous comment are identical in effect. If one method is to be preferred it can only be in terms of style. There won't be any behavioural differences.

Comment: `MyArray := nil` is only a modification of a memory address. But `SetLength` and `Finalize` need to execute much more instructions than that. So, if this program is running in a mission that send a robot to Jupiter, `MyArray := nil` will save hundreds of lagoons of fuel.

Comment: Not so. All three variants compile to the same code. This is a managed type. Setting the variable to nil involves decrementing reference count and potentially destroying array.

Comment: @CharlieH "_MyArray := nil is only a modification of a memory address_" That assertion is absolutely false! And if it were true, you'd have a memory leak; which would have have made it a completely **wrong** choice. Lucky for you though, all the clean-up the other 2 options do, is also done by `MyArray := nil`.